# Secure storage of database credentials

Tags: php, database, security

Had a major problem recently where my web hosting company messed up and all my php files were displayed in plain text. This was a major issue for me for obvious reasons. Mainly because mysql database details were exposed.

I am now trying to change the way in which my php files get the login information for the database so that this will never happen again even if the hosting company fail me.

my current set up looks like this :

```
     include 'info.php';

    class Login {

var $host;
var $username;
var $password;
var $db;
var $url;
```

Inside the info.php is the username, password and so on for the database. I want to make it so that the info.php file can never be viewed and only my .php files are able to access info.php in order to get the login infomation.

How can i set this up? This is a bit of a tricky one for me to explain so please dont be harsh and -1 me for a bad description.. just ask and i will clear up any gaps in my description.

Comment: You might need to take a hard look at the source & age of your code. The `var $host` was the way to define class variables in **php 4**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply place `info.php` outside your webroot. This way, you can include it, but should your web hosting f*#$ up, no one else can view that file, even as plain text.

You would then include it like this:

`include('../info.php');`

This way, even if someone finds out that you have a file called `info.php` that stores all your passwords, they cannot point their browser to that file.

The above would be the ideal and most watertight solution. However, if that is not possible due to permissions, the other option would be to place all sensitive files in a directory and block direct access to that directory using a `.htaccess` file.

In the directory you want to block off access to, place an `.htaccess` file with the following contents:

`deny from all`

Comment: Would this be outside of the public_html folder?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Anywhere outside the `public_html` folder

Comment: I have a problem where by i dont have permissions to place anything outside of public_html. Guessing this has been limited by hosting company...

Comment: You can achieve something similar with .htaccess files. See edit.

Comment: It seemed to have worked but to confirm my .htaccess file contains deny from all and thats it. will that achive what i need?

Comment: Yes, that is all it should contain. It will deny access to the directory it exists in. To confirm, create a test file in that directory and point your browser to it.

Comment: You're all suggesting to store credentials outside wwwroot. Ok, I understand the security background. But how should it be stored in version control then (sample config)? Usually wwwroot is the root of git repo, so if there is anything outside - it will be outside of VC. Imagine new developer trying to set up a local instance for development - how should he know magic like "take this file, copy it outside and fill in"?

Comment: @TheGodfather I don't think you should be checking in credentials into git anyways. I'd suggest a README/setup instructions that explain the credentials file needs to be created along with an error message like "DB credentials file not found at ..."

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason xbonez's answer doesn't work (lets say one doesn't have access to a non document_root folder)..  You can achieve the same thing by using .htaccess

```
<files info.php>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</files>
```

This, should in theory (non tested) protect the file from being used in the browser but not block php from including said file.

Answer (score -2):

Create form that redirect to file for the example "requests.php" and make switch on it for all you requests.If your data is right redirect to the specific page, if not do it same.On the end of the switch put anoter redirect.With this way user can't see that page.Don't put therer html or something - only logic.

Comment: Probably this doesn't answer the question, but in general I assume that the idea behind this answer is pretty reasonable. "Create a router". Almost all modern web apps nowadays include URL routing in some way. And apart of other advantages it could help in restricting access as well.